# Controller does not receive value from view (implementing search function) on MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make a page with a search function. When you first go to the page, all you have is a search bar. When you type something into the search bar and click the "submit" or "search" button, I want the value in the search box to be submitted to the controller as a string. Then, this value can be used in returning the a model back to the page. Here's what I have so far:

Search.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@ViewBag.PageTitle
<h1>Search All Issues</h1>
<form asp-controller="Report" asp-action="Search" method="get">
<input name="searchstr" id="Search" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

ReportController.cs

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search(string test)
    {
        ViewBag.PageTitle = test;
        var report = _context.Reports.ToList();
        return View(report);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? For now, it would be nice if I can just get that ViewBag.PageTitle to appear on the page. If I can do that, then I can return the report model just the way I want.

Also, a few additional questions. Some of the stuff I've seen on stack overflow has a recommendation to do a Post in the controller. If I do that, the page errors out. Why is a get needed for this? Intuitively, it makes more sense to me to use a Post...

Comment: Your input has `name="searchstr` which does not match the name of your parameter which is `test` - change the input to `<input name="test" />` **OR** the parameter to `(string searchstr)`

Comment: And a GET is usually more appropriate (allows user to bookmark the search results, navigate back etc)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was extremely close; Stephen Muecke had the correct answer. I simply needed to change my input name or parameter name.

I made this mistake as I was considering this from a C++/C standpoint where the parameter names can be irrelevant. I see now, though, that with ASP.NET MVC, you need to have the input name match the parameter name.

Thanks for the help!